# Angular firestore get document field as string

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, rxjs-observables

I know there is a ton of questions like this, but none of the solutions solve my problem.
IVe been stuck on this for a while, and would really appreciate some help/guidance.
I suppose there is something big I am missing in the ideas of observable, cloud firestore, etc...

**Primary Issue:** How can I get a single document field from cloud firestore db as a string?
I attempted two different approaches and niether gave me the results i need:

```
getUsername(uid : string) {
    const user = this.afs.firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`)
    return user.get().then((doc) => {
        return (doc.exists ? doc.data().username : null);})

} //this one returns a promise and i need a string
```

```
getUsername(uid : string) {
    let answer;
    this.get(uid).valueChanges().subscribe((doc) => answer = doc.username) //intellisense reccomended username as m attribute which was hopeful
    return answer;
} //this returns undefined
```

**Quick aside**- ive seen people use the rxjs map operator to access the fields in an object, like

`getUsername() return userDoc.pipe(map(user => user.username))`

I tried this one too, and it did not work. I also checked the rxjs documentation and it said the intended use of map was for applying an operation to observable stream. Can it be used like how shown above? ( and if so, what am i doing wrong? )

**Details/background:**
I am using Google Firebase for both authentication and Firestore cloud db. The problem arises because users create a user account through my application (creating a new user document in the users collection), but on the backend, i use firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword method- so there is two seperate instances of user data- google record and my application. To resolve this, I use the firebase.user.uid as the uid for the user document, and sync googles data with my application db during runtime, so that if a user changes their gmail address, their user document has the most up to date email address. The problem here is that I have a seperate collection "profiles" that stores the user public profile and preference data, where username is used as the uid, and also is used as query parameter in the url like

`localhost/4200/profiles/username`

so for here, the username has to be one word without spaces. I validate for this in the create-account form, but there is a separate issue now- google username can contain spaces. So when I sync the google account with my user document, i have to use two data sources.

```
userDoc.set({
username : from user document
email : from firebase.User.email
uid : Firebase.User.uid
})
```

and so, a few questions arise from this.

1. how do i get a single firestore document field **as a string** rather than an promise, observable, [object object] etc..?
2. should i go back to the drawing board with this whole situation- (

ie

- redesign my db so that profile is a subcollection of user
- find a way to navigate to profile page without using username as a route parameter
- think of a better plan for authentication, so that there isnt a seperate db table that needs to get        synced to googles auth data whenever the user logs in

Any help or suggestion(s) are greatly appreciated

Comment: I would try having a global variable and assigning the result to the variable instead of returning an asynchronous call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try in my component ts

```
...
username:string
...

constructor(private db:FirestoreService)

...

getUsername(){
  this.db.getUsername(someUID).subscribe(
    (data) => this.username = data.exists ? data.data().username : undefined
  }
}
```

and in FirestoreService ts

```
getUsername(uid : string) {
    return (this.afs.firestore.doc(`users/${uid}`).get())
}
```

now to answer a few questions (that's normally only one problem at a time), you can find many tutorial to have both a firebase authentification and specific user infos on firestore or realtime database.

You cannot return an asynchronous retrieved value in a syncronous flow you'll always have to update your app later with the desired value after being retrieved from the db.